# Selecting records based on two other tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query with inner join to another table, with this I want also include records which are contained in another column.

Example:

```
select name, address from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

With this, I want to also include rows which are having `table1.recno = (1,2,4)`.

How could I write query for that?

One option I know is to use the `IN` keyword instead of the first table join. But our client doesn't want to use the IN keyword.

Comment: @Jenn, if you don't like IN - you can use EXISTS, (very strange requirement - does not use IN)

Comment: There can be a reason for not using IN, if I remember correctly. I think "IN" will scan the entire table, whereas using EXISTS will stop as soon as a matching record is found. I can't remember where I read that though, and how reliable the source was, so I may be completely wrong

Comment: `IN` is syntactic sugar for (a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 4).  Asking to not use it is like trying to use a PC without a mouse...

Comment: @A S, if you're using a subquery *inside* the brackets for the IN clause, this would be true of the subquery. For a list of values inside the brackets (as in the question), this shouldn't be applicable.

Comment: @Jenn, do you know *why* the client doesn't want to use the `IN` keyword? Is it for the reason described by A S?

Comment: @Mark - Yup, that makes perfect sense. Would be interesting to know the reasons for not using IN, as you say. If not the performance issue, then my only guess would be that a dynamic CSL is being passed in which the filter will use, but I don't think that's it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join and then use the WHERE clause to filter out the rows that you need.

```
select name, address 
from table1 
    left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where
    table2.id IS NOT NULL OR table1.ID In (1,2,4)
```

Or if you want to avoid an innocuous `IN` for silly reasons, use:

```
select name, address 
from table1 
    left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where
    table2.id IS NOT NULL 
  OR table1.ID = 1
  OR table1.ID = 2
  OR table1.ID = 4
```

Comment: [quote]One option I know is to use the IN keyword instead of the first table join. But our client doesn't want to use the IN keyword.[/quote]

Comment: No, why would you think that?

Comment: Ah, my mistake - the direct quote from the question without further elaboration led me to think that the OP was re-emphasising the significant part of the question.